# how to properly load pickled machine learning models on server

Tags: machine-learning, flask, pickle

It is a Python Flask app.

The same code works in my local when I run this app on local. But on a server that I rent from DigitalOcean, it gives me this problem.
I have been trying to load this machine learning model(a classification model I trained using sklearn) at run. But it gives me this error OR sometimes, with some solutions I saw in Stackoverflow added, hangs forever.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0
```

I tried every solution in Stackoverflow: like adding encoding="latin-1" or "bytes" on loading the pickle. I tried below and many other combinations with different arguments that people recommended in Stackoverflow.

```
def load_model(file_path):
    script_directory = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
    abs_filepath = os.path.join(script_directory, file_path)
    with open(abs_filepath, 'rb') as f:
        classifier = pickle.loads(f.read())
    return classifier

def load_model(file_path):
        script_directory = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
        abs_filepath = os.path.join(script_directory, file_path)
        with open(abs_filepath, 'r') as f:
                               # also with 'rb'
            classifier = pickle.load(f, encoding="bytes")
                               # also with "latin-1" "latin1" etc.. and load, loads, f, and f.read()
        return classifier

model = load_model("modelname.pickle")
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as there is a problem when you pickle the model using python2 and try to load this model using python3.

- Did you try to load this model using Python 2?
- Do you have the same mistake when you run it with parameter encoding=latin1? If it is a different error maybe you need to run

```
    dill._dill._reverse_typemap["ObjectType"] = object
```

before loading it.

The problem is described pretty well here:
https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/convert-py2-pickles-to-py3/

Comment: Odd thing is that the models are properly loaded in function level, the functions that uses the load_model function.

But when load_model is used out of any functions, it makes that problem.

For example,

def classify(data):
    classifier = load_model('model.pickle')
    #do more things.